# React Component updated before Dom event is fired (onBlur and onClick)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

I have a react datalist component (input field and list of options) and two Dom events I am listening to.

1. onBlur of the input field
2. onClick of the list items

The problem is, that the onBlur event hides the list items.

When I click an item the onBlur event is triggered first and updates the list items to be hidden. Apparently, as the list items are updated their onClick event is never fired.

Right now I am wrapping the onBlur event in a 500ms timeout, but this seems hacky and is not a nice user experience.

Is there a common solution to this problem?

Here is a code sample: [Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxXwoY)

```
class DatalistOption extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (evt) => {
    console.log("onClick for Option called")
    this.props.select(evt);
  }

  ...
}


class ReactDatalist extends React.Component {
  ...
  handleInputBlur = () => {
    console.log("onBlur called")
    //setTimeout(() => this.setState({ hide: true }), 500); // such a hack, that I am ashamed...
    this.setState({ hide: true })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can help :D

Comment: I added a working code sample. Hope this helps to  understand the problem